# Question from Do Carmo's Differential Forms and Applications

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

[image]

> In this question, I've already done the item a) by following the hint. I'm struggling (even with the hint) to calculate item b). I believe I have to follow the steps in the proof of Poincaré's Lemma, however I couldn't obtain the integration of $H^*w$ as indicated in the hint. Would someone help me in how to obtain the expression in item b)? Thanks in advance.

I've done some progress, but I coudn't find the final result.

**MY ATTEMPT:**
Considering the contraction

$H: \mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ given by $H(p,t)=(tx, ty, tz)$.

Calculating the differential, we have

$dH=(xdt+tdx, ydt+tdy, zdt+tdz)$.

Now remembering that $\omega=Ady\wedge dz + Bdz\wedge dx+ Cdx\wedge dy$ in item a), the pullback is

$\begin{align*}
\overline{\omega}&= H^*\omega=\omega (dH)=\\
&=A(tx, ty, tz)(ydt+tdy)\wedge(zdt+tdz)+\\
&+B(tx, ty, tz)(zdt+tdz)\wedge(xdt+tdx)+\\
&+C(tx, ty, tz)(xdt+tdx)\wedge(ydt+tdy)\\
\end{align*}$

$\begin{align*}
&=A(tx, ty, tz)(tydt\wedge dz+tzdy\wedge dt+t^2dy\wedge dz)\\
&+B(tx, ty, tz)(zt dt\wedge dx+txdz\wedge dt + t^2 dz^dx)\\
&+C(tx, ty, tz)(xtdt\wedge dy+ tydx\wedge dt+t^2dx\wedge dy)
\end{align*}$

Comment: Edit your question to include your effort to compute $H^*\omega$. Remember that he says $+$ terms without $dt$, so what he's written shows only that portion of the pullback of $A\,dy\wedge dz$ that contains $dt$.

Comment: Hi, I added my effort, I thing I was able to compute $H*\omega$ but I failed in the  integration. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: So, take your form and put $dt$ in front, remembering that to switch two 1-forms introduces a negative. You get exactly the integral he has written down.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I will writte down.